# Not all duplicate rows being removed

Tags: c#

I've made a console application that will grab data from a database and then export it to a csv file, I have been made aware though that in the file there are duplicate rows and I am struggling to find a way to remove them all. The query for getting the data is like so:

```
        private static string HistoryQuery(Guid itemDetailId) {
           var sql = $@"
Select IH.ItemDetailID, i.Type, v.Number, v.Title, ISNULL(CAST(V.MajorRevisionNumber AS VARCHAR(10) ), '') +'.'+
ISNULL(CAST(V.MinorRevisionNumber AS VARCHAR(10) ) , '')  AS RevisionNumber,
Ih.Action, id2.Title AS ActionedBy, Ih.ActionedDate, Ih.Comment, iwft.Type as TaskType, iwft.StartDate,
iwft.CompletedDate, Iwft.Status, Iwft.Outcome, id3.Title AS TaskActionedBy, Iwfta.ActionDate, Iwfta.Action AS TaskAction, Iwfta.Comment AS TaskComment, lid.URL
From ItemView v
Join ItemHistory Ih
    On Ih.ItemDetailID = v.ItemDetailId
Join Item i
    On i.ItemID = v.ItemId
Left Outer join ItemWorkflowTask Iwft
    On Iwft.ItemDetailID = v.ItemDetailId
Left outer Join ItemWorkflowTaskAction Iwfta
    On Iwfta.ItemWorkflowTaskID = Iwft.ItemWorkflowTaskID
Left outer Join DocumentItemDetail did 
    ON did.ItemDetailID = Ih.ItemDetailID
Left outer Join ItemDetail id
    ON id.ItemID = did.LinkItemID
Left outer Join LinkItemDetail lid
    ON lid.ItemDetailID = id.ItemDetailID
Left outer Join ItemDetail id2
    ON id2.ItemID = ih.ActionedBy
Left outer Join ItemDetail id3
    ON id3.ItemID = iwfta.ActionedBy
Where IH.ItemDetailID = '{itemDetailId}'
AND Ih.Action NOT IN ('Access', 'AddToFavourites', 'ItemDefaultFavouriteChanged', 'RemoveFromFavourites', 'View')
AND (I.Type = 'Document' OR I.Type = 'ProcessMap')
GROUP BY
IH.ItemDetailID, i.Type, v.Number, v.Title, ISNULL(CAST(V.MajorRevisionNumber AS VARCHAR(10) ), '') +'.'+
ISNULL(CAST(V.MinorRevisionNumber AS VARCHAR(10) ) , ''),
Ih.Action, id2.Title, Ih.ActionedDate, Ih.Comment, iwft.Type, iwft.StartDate,
iwft.CompletedDate, Iwft.Status, Iwft.Outcome, id3.Title, Iwfta.ActionDate, Iwfta.Action, Iwfta.Comment, lid.URL";

            return sql;
        }
```

Now without the group by I was getting 2083 rows with 210 duplicates but after adding it I am getting 2031 rows with 158 duplicates and these are the ones I can't seem to get rid of.

The data table where the values are stored is made up like so:

```
        public DataTable GetExtractData(List<Guid>ItemDetailIds)
        {
            var historyTable = new DataTable();
            using var cnn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
            foreach(var itemDetailId in ItemDetailIds)
            {
                AddDataToTable(HistoryQuery(itemDetailId), cnn, historyTable);
            }


            DataTable replaceNulls = historyTable.Clone();
#pragma warning disable CS8602 // Dereference of a possibly null reference.
            replaceNulls.Columns["TaskActionedBy"].DataType = typeof(string);
#pragma warning restore CS8602 // Dereference of a possibly null reference.
            foreach (DataRow row in historyTable.Rows)
            {
                replaceNulls.ImportRow(row);
            }

            foreach (DataRow row in replaceNulls.Rows)
            {
                if (row["TaskActionedBy"] is DBNull)
                {
                    row["TaskActionedBy"] = "";
                }

               row["Comment"]= row["Comment"].ToString().Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "");
               row["TaskComment"] = row["Comment"].ToString().Replace("\n", "").Replace("\r", "");

            }

            return replaceNulls;
        }



   private static DataTable AddDataToTable(string query, SqlConnection connection, DataTable tableToFill)
    {
        using var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);

        var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adapter.Fill(tableToFill);

        return tableToFill;
    }
```

I tried adding something like:

```
    private DataTable RemoveDuplicateRecords(DataTable dt)
    {
        var uniqueRows = dt.AsEnumerable().Distinct(DataRowComparer.Default);
        DataTable uniqueData = uniqueRows.CopyToDataTable();
        return uniqueData;
    }
```

And then in the GetExtractData method do:

```
        DataTable uniqueTable = RemoveDuplicateRecords(replaceNulls);

        return uniqueTable;
```

but that has made no difference, and it stays at 2031 rows.

I know there are duplicates as when I click on "Remove Duplicates" under the data table in Excel it is removing a bunch. I'm not sure where I've gone wrong, I'm assuming it is do with how I've written my query but I am not sure where the mistake is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a fix which may not be best practice but it sorts the issue,

After I have the data table, I then get it into a list like so:

```
    public List<ExtractDocument> GetExtractDocuments(List<Guid>ItemDetailIds)
    {
        var items = GetExtractData(ItemDetailIds);

        return items.Select().Select(item => new ExtractDocument
        {
            ItemDetailId = item.Field<Guid>("ItemDetailID"),
            ItemNumber = item.Field<string>("Number"),
            ItemTitle = item.Field<string>("Title"),    
            ItemRevision = item.Field<string>("RevisionNumber"),
            ActionType = item.Field<string>("Action"),
            ActionedBy = item.Field<string>("ActionedBy"),
            ActionedDate = item.Field<DateTime?>("ActionedDate")?.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"),
            Comment = item.Field<string>("Comment"),
            TaskType = item.Field<string>("TaskType"),
            StartDate = item.Field<DateTime?>("StartDate")?.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"),
            CompletedDate = item.Field<DateTime?>("CompletedDate")?.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"),
            Status = item.Field<string>("Status"),
            Outcome = item.Field<string>("Outcome"),
            ActionerName = item.Field<string>("TaskActionedBy"),
            DateActioned = item.Field<DateTime?>("ActionDate")?.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"),
            ActionTaken = item.Field<string>("TaskAction"),
            TaskComment = item.Field<string>("TaskComment"),
            Link = item.Field<string>("URL")
        }).Distinct().ToList();

    }
```

Adding the .Distinct() fixes the issue and I no longer have duplicate rows in the created csv file.

I'm assuming the issue is to do with what columns I am doing the joins on, but these are the ones that they have to be on as there aren't any other columns that would work

Edit:

So after doing a bit more digging I found that were actually no duplicates, when I change the date format from "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" to "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff", there were no duplicates appearing in the excel file. What has happening is that the rows were essentially the same but in the date fields they had different milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use **"SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2..."** in your SQL query? It must remove all the identical rows from the result table

Comment: yes I've tried distinct but no change unfortunately

Comment: @lross15 Are you saying Distinct does not remove duplicate rows? Probably they are not duplicates in that case.

Comment: @Magnus it does not. Well when I'm looking at the data in the csv file, the rows are exactly the same, so not sure why they're not being seen as duplicates? But like I said in my answer using .Distinct() when the data is in a list does remove them

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).